# How do I disable one button after another is clicked?

Tags: jquery

```
$('#stats').click(function(){
    $( "#upg" ).prop( "disabled", true );
});
```

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't seem to work. I was trying to get `#upg` to disable when `#stats` was clicked.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. Also, you have a ` in your example

Comment: IIRC, you should use `.attr` instead of `.prop` for things like this but I'll be honest I don't really recall the difference right now.

Comment: @Jhecht, you removed the ` I referred to but how do you know that's not in the OP's code and is the cause of the problem? Also, `.prop()` is the correct tool for the disabled attribute and `.attr()` isn't. Read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps

```js
var disabled = false;
$('#btn_1').click(function(){
   disabled = !disabled;
      $("#btn_2").prop('disabled', disabled);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn_1">
Button 1
</button>
<button id="btn_2">
Button 2
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use $.attr('disabled','true'); for on click of Stats button.

**The Code will be like:**

```
 $('#stats').click(function() {

$('#upg').attr('disabled','true');

});
```

View this Live at JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/meumairakram/uwrL2xfo/1/

Comment: Or add your Demo of Project on Git or JS Fiddle So, I can Help you easily! :-)

Comment: From the docs: "As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. **To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.**"